# Missing files when I'm installing mysql

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal, homebrew

I tried several time to install/uninstall mysql.
I still have the same error message :

```
Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Indeed, there is no mysql.sock on tmp

Here after an exemple :

```
brew install mysql
```

Then i got

```
Updating Homebrew...
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/mysql-8.0.19_1.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/myname/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/d8a3b1d8709c6ed74cfe9b16bb61a8770b811043a3b3e5791ec615beab5f41ec--mysql-8.0.19_1.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring mysql-8.0.19_1.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
We've installed your MySQL database without a root password. To secure it run:
    mysql_secure_installation

MySQL is configured to only allow connections from localhost by default

To connect run:
    mysql -uroot

To have launchd start mysql now and restart at login:
  brew services start mysql
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  mysql.server start
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.19_1: 286 files, 288.8MB
```

So I run

```
sudo mysql.server start
```

And I got

```
Starting MySQL
.Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/MacBook-Pro-de-Samantha.local.err'.
.. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/MacBook-Pro-de-myname.local.pid).
```

So I

```
ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
```

There is no *MacBook-Pro-de-myname.local.pid* on /usr/local/var/mysql too

I also tempted

```
mysql_secure_installation
```

And enter a password for user root.

I always got this error message :

```
Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I already try to installing MySQL on macOS using native packages from dev.mysql.com, but still same issues.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I just tried `brew install mysql` on my Mojave box, and it works fine for me.

Installation log:

```
==> Pouring mysql-8.0.19_1.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
==> /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.19_1/bin/mysqld --initialize-insecure --user=rchen --basedir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.19_1 --datadir=/
==> Caveats
We've installed your MySQL database without a root password. To secure it run:
    mysql_secure_installation

MySQL is configured to only allow connections from localhost by default

To connect run:
    mysql -uroot

To have launchd start mysql now and restart at login:
  brew services start mysql
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  mysql.server start
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.19_1: 286 files, 288.8MB
```

run log

```
$ brew services start mysql
==> Tapping homebrew/services
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 48, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (48/48), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (44/44), done.
remote: Total 825 (delta 18), reused 16 (delta 3), pack-reused 777
Receiving objects: 100% (825/825), 231.32 KiB | 4.36 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (335/335), done.
Tapped 1 command (40 files, 310.6KB).
==> Successfully started `mysql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mysql)
```

`$ mysql_secure_installation`

```
$ mysql_secure_installation

Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Connecting to MySQL using a blank password.

VALIDATE PASSWORD COMPONENT can be used to test passwords
and improve security. It checks the strength of password
and allows the users to set only those passwords which are
secure enough. Would you like to setup VALIDATE PASSWORD component?

Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No: y

There are three levels of password validation policy:

LOW    Length >= 8
MEDIUM Length >= 8, numeric, mixed case, and special characters
STRONG Length >= 8, numeric, mixed case, special characters and dictionary                  file

Please enter 0 = LOW, 1 = MEDIUM and 2 = STRONG: 0
Please set the password for root here.

New password:

Re-enter new password:
Sorry, passwords do not match.

New password:

Re-enter new password:

Estimated strength of the password: 25
```